# Linq to Xml and custom xml entities

Tags: c#, xml, linq, mathml

I want to create a MathML document from an expression tree using Linq to xml, but I cannot figure out how to use the MathML xml entities (such as ⁡ and &InvisibleTimes):
When I try to create directly a XElement using

```
XElement xe = new XElement("mo", "&InvisibleTimes");
```

it justs escapes the ampersand (which is no good).
I also tried to use XElement.Parse

```
XElement xe = new XElement.Parse("<mo>&InvisibleTimes</mo>");
```

but it fails with an System.XmlException: Reference to undeclared entity 'InvisibleTimes'
How can I declare the entity or ignore the checks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have pointed out, there is no direct way to do it.

That said, you can try using the corresponding unicode caracther. According to http://www.w3.org/TR/MathML2/mmlalias.html, for ApplyFunction it is 02061, try new XElement("mo", "\u02061")

Comment: This doesn't work: "XElement("mo", "\u02061")". I don't know why this is the accepted answer...

Answer (score 2):

According to [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/linqprojectgeneral/thread/abd9d8cc-30cc-45f1-8bd9-652a15b2b491), LINQ to XML doesn't include entity references: it doesn't have any node type for them. It just expands them as it loads a file, and after that you've just got "normal" characters.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about `XDocument`, but you can do it with `XmlDocument`:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
var entity = doc.CreateEntityReference("InvisibleTimes");
XmlElement root = (XmlElement)doc.AppendChild(doc.CreateElement("xml"));
var el = root.AppendChild(doc.CreateElement("mo")).AppendChild(entity);
string s = doc.OuterXml;
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to xml encode the names because '&' is a special character.

So instead of

```
XElement xe = new XElement("mo", "&InvisibleTimes");
```

try

```
XElement xe = new XElement("mo", "&amp;InvisibleTimes");
```

Comment: (I edited to show the formatting) That looks to actually make things worse: <mo>&amp;amp;InvisibleTimes</mo>

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need a DTD to define <mo>⁢</mo>.

MathML 2.0 provides an XHTML + MathML DTD.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround is to use any placeholder for the & such as `;_amp_;`
`XElement xe = new XElement("mo", ";_amp_;InvisibleTimes)`
and restore it when you get the xml string:
`output = xe.ToString().Replace(";_amp_;", "&")`