# In C# Using System.Xml.Linq XText how do I get an & in the document instead of &amp;

Tags: c#, xml, linq

Using MS Visual Studio 2013 to create a C# application, I am trying to get the following output in an XML document.

```
<UnitsOfMeasure>
    &uom-data;
</UnitsOfMeasure>
```

I keep getting

```
<UnitsOfMeasure>
    &amp;uom-data;
</UnitsOfMeasure>
```

Here is the code I have tried

```
XElement uom = new XElement("UnitsOfMeasure");
uom.Add("\n" + tab2, new XText("&uom-data;"), "\n" + tab1);
sd.Add("\n" + tab1, uom);
sd.Add("\n");

XElement uom = new XElement("UnitsOfMeasure");
uom.Add("\n" + tab2, new XText((char)38 + "uom-data;"), "\n" + tab1);
sd.Add("\n" + tab1, uom);
sd.Add("\n");
```

Thanks

Comment: That first one is not [valid xml](http://keylimetie.com/blog/2008/9/25/how-to-safely-escape-invalid-xml-characters/).  You have to encode certain characters and `&` is one of them, so the second one is correct.

Comment: @juharr - actually it *could be* valid Xml. I explain further in my answer.

Comment: If you are trying to write an entity then this might be a duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/707062/linq-to-xml-and-custom-xml-entities

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that & has a special meaning in XML - it's used to escape other things; see [beware of the ampersand when using xml](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/beware-of-the-ampersand-when-using-xml/), for example. What's being written for you is the correct way to include an ampersand inside XML and when an XML parser reads it back in, it should convert the & back to &.

So perhaps, if anything, you may have a problem with whatever code is reading that XML back in again as it should be converting it back for you.

Answer (score 0):

XML has things called "entities", which take the form `ampersand-characters-semicolon`.

The XML entity is a alias for a different block of text (although in most cases, entities are just used just to insert a single character -- generally characters not on the keyboard)

`&amp;` is the most commonly used -- it's to insert an `&`.  `&copy;` is for the copyright symbol.

In addition to the standard ones, you are allowed to define your own.

The fact that what you are trying to enter -- `&uom-data;` -- so neatly follows the entity format, I suspect that it really IS an entity and you are just missing the part where it's defined.